# SQL Server : OFFSET FETCH performs scan while TOP WHERE performs seek?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I got the following two queries. One is fast the other is slow.

The table has a clusted index on the `Id` column.

```
-- Slow, uses clustered index scan reading 100100 rows
SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Foo] 
ORDER BY Id
OFFSET 100000 ROWS FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY

-- Fast, uses clustered index seek reading 100 rows
SELECT TOP 100 * 
FROM [dbo].[Foo]
WHERE Id > 100000
ORDER BY Id
```

The plans are identical except for one uses a scan the other a seek.

Can anyone explain why or is this simply how `OFFSET` works?

The table is very wide with a few `NVARCHAR(100-200)` and a single `NVARCHAR(2500)` column.

Comment: Note: Those queries are not the same!

Comment: OFFSET must scan to count rows, ID>.. must not. An they may give different results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries are not equivalent.  Although *you* might assume that the `id`s have no gaps and start at 1, the database engine does not know that.

Indexes are organized to find particular values quickly.  They generally do this by traversing a tree structure, and one which is generally balanced.  You can read more about this in the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177443(v=sql.105).aspx).

However, they are not organized to quickly get to the *nth* row in the table.  Hence, the query needs to scan the table to count the number of rows.

That said, the index *could* do what you want if it kept the number of rows in each child.  Do realize that this would complicate modifications to the table, because the entire hierarchy would need to be updated for each `update`, `insert`, and `delete`.

Comment: Thank you. Good point. I thought that by using statistics it would have known much of the range was continous. But thinking about its clear that the two queries do totally different things and are not at all equivalent.